# Twig Extension Error, Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have problem with Twig Extension. I would like to check if my variable match a regex. But i Got error.

My twig extension Class:

```
<?php
// src/GL/HomeBundle/Twig/LastNameExtension.php
namespace GL\HomeBundle\Twig;

class LastNameExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {  
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('lastName', 'lastNameFunction')
        );
    }

    public function lastNameFunction($lastName)
    {
        $pattern = "/^[1-9]\d\d\-\d\d\d\-\d\d\-\d\d$/";

        return preg_match($pattern, $lastName);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'lastName';
    }
}
?>
```

And part of my  services.xml file

```
<services>
    <service id="gl.twig.lastName" class="GL\HomeBundle\Twig\LastNameExtension">
        <tag name="twig.extension" />
    </service>
</services>
```

The error i got is:
`: Error: Call to undefined function lastNameFunction() in         C:\xampp\htdocs\wp_ubezpieczenia\app\cache\dev\twig\10\4c\8503d697949a099f75aa8c4c41a2.php line 156`

I will be very gratefull for any help with this.

Comment: It should work. What Symfony version are you using ? Did you cleared the cache completely ? Can you copy paste the code of the line where the error occurs in your cached file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `new \Twig_SimpleFunction('lastName', 'lastNameFunction')` with `new \Twig_SimpleFunction('lastName', array($this, 'lastNameFunction'))`, otherwise you are calling the function "lastNameFunction", not the method "LastNameExtension::lastNameFunction".

Answer (score -1):

use

`'lastName'=> new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'lastNameFunction')` instead

and call function in twig with

`{{ lastName(myvalue) }}`

Comment: `Twig_Function_Method` is deprecated!